# Where can I find data from released computer models?

Tags: data-request, products

I am looking for an open database containing information about released computer models. This information has to contain the Stock Keeping Unit (SKU) number, which is a unique ID for computers, and information such that the processor model, amount of RAM etc.

Cnet has a solution called [DataSource](http://demo.cnetcontent.com/product-information.html) which looks to be what I am looking for, but it is not open data and I don't want to buy their solution without knowing the quality of the service.

Does anyone know if such a database exists?

Comment: For apple products, they used to have the 'tech info library' with machine specs, but it now sends you to a more generic support page (not just hardware).  I don't think it has SKUs ... although there are ways to [decode an apple serial number](http://www.appleserialnumberinfo.com/Desktop/index.php)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Joe. I think it is possible to find specific information on many of the manufacturers websites, but not in a standarized way, which makes it difficult to get information from different providers.

Comment: Here's a dataset from 1987! https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Computer+Hardware (Maybe it's time we make a new one.)

Answer (score 1):

I think in your search you should use either the term "specifications" or "specs", as in "computer specs". "Information" is too vague and in the jargon of technology specs/specifications is the way to go.

To get you started, I would suggest looking for non-commercial groups that are collecting data on hardware. For example, the groups doing the Energy Star rating, groups collecting data for import and selling purposes, groups conducting safety tests, etc.

One quick example: As part of the **old** EU Energy Star program, there is an Excel file with the type of specs you are looking for. **Unfortunately**, the manufactorers are masked. But it's a start.

- [Overview](http://www.eu-energystar.org/en/index.html)
- [All Downloads](http://www.eu-energystar.org/en/253.shtml#computers)
- [Computers version 5.0 - Final - Masked Dataset [XLS]](http://www.eu-energystar.org/downloads/specifications/20081118/Computer%20Data_Final_Masked.xls)

If there is any newer data, you'll have to register: [link](http://beta.eu-energystar.org/home/).