# Where can I find data about released product models? (e.g. Computers)

Tags: data-request, products

I am searching for a dataset containing multivariate product information. For example about notebooks with data as price, color, size, cpu speed, ram, hard drive capacity, number of usb ports, CD slot, etc. - even better if the set says where I am able to but it for which price. The focus however is on the product attributes. It could be completely different products as well (e.g. shoes), but I guess technical product would have the greatest number of quantifiable features.

I looked at the suggestions from [Where can I find data from released computer models?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/where-can-i-find-data-from-released-computer-models) but the links lead to 404s or the data is *really* old.